# How to run on RedShift sql script file programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, .net, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to run SQL script file (located, for example, on S3) on Amazon Redshift using Java or C#? I can execute stand-alone commands using AWS SDK and Npgsql for .NET, but I can't find the method for running the stand-alone file.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to tell RedShift to execute an SQL command stored elsewhere.

You would need to retrieve the script and then pass it to RedShift via JDBC/ODBC, in the same way that you are running stand-alone commands.